# how to prevent unexpected data from causing fatal crash of nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io-1.0

Despite my extensive experience with nginx, apache, jboss etc. servers, I am very new to nodejs server (It took my interest for socket.io features). I find it strange that unexpected data like say object.MyProperty (which is undefined) etc - which are trivial in my opinion, cause the entire server to crash (it doesnt crash for that client request, but the entire server crashes!) and you need to restart the server.

I am not sure if it is because I am on development mode or it will be like that on live mode as well. When it crashes, all runtime data get lost.
My question is that what should I do make sure that the server doesnt crash but it can write issues to the log file like in other servers.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try` `catch` blocks for this. And `log` them under `catch`.

---

**Updated:**

Also, `Node` being single process based, uncaught exceptions leads to crash (of that process). One of the methods suggested is to use [`domains`](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html).
Example:

```
domain = require('domain'),
d = domain.create();

d.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});

d.run(function() {
   ...
```

[Ref.](http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/) is a good article and explains in short various approaches to handle the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you can't really predict some unexpected issues which can appear in real world application in production mode. For example, say I am using functions from third-party modules. There might be cases which we can not predict in advance but those third-party functions may not like  parameter length etc. It is sometimes not reasonable to put try{} catch{} everywhere. Due to one issue, all client connections got broken. It is ok if that particular request fails due to abnormal data, but it shouldn't crash the entire server. Doesn't it make the server very vulnerable?

Comment: @Konul updating answer (in short you can try `domain` - look for docs)

Answer (score 1):

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message)
  console.error(err.stack)
})
```

Since nodejs is a single process server, you can place this code anywhere in js script for this to act as a catch all for unhandled/unforeseen errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for https://github.com/foreverjs/forever. Forever runs a script forever and restarts it in the event of a crash without user intervention.

You can install forever using npm. Once installed, you can run your nodejs scripts using `forever start <path/to/script>`. `forever list` will list all the currently running scripts and `forever stop <script-id>` will stop a given script.

Keep in mind that using this doesn't mean you don't have to do proper exception handling. Implement `try...catch` statements as needed and handle all exceptions in code.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I actually tried forever. But it just technically restarts the server after it crashes. Runtime data of other clients still get lost. For example, say website A uses nodejs server. You and me visit this site. I make very strange input etc. somehow (let's not go to details how), my request fails with error. You request fails as well. Some data like file pointers, socket pointer etc, can not really be stored and re-used. So, say in the case of chat application, everyone's instance crashes and loses all data.

Comment: Ideally, there should not be any crashes. Forever is just a backup in case all hell breaks loose unexpectedly. As @nash_ag suggested `domain` can be used to handle unexpected and uncaught exceptions. So a combination of both would be ideal i guess?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be for you to validate all your incoming post request bodies using a json schema validator. There are several available that are really fast and will add very minimal overhead (less than 1 ms) to your overall response time. I'm the author of one such validator called [Themis](https://github.com/playlyfe/themis) which we use for REST APIs. There's also a comprehensive [benchmark](https://github.com/Muscula/json-schema-benchmark) which compares all the available JSON schema validators.

This would prevent your sever from crashing and becoming unavailable simply because of a bad request.